# Scrape Instagram names with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make Instagram scraper with BeautifulSoup. I just want to get the name of the profile. (I'm using Jennifer Lopez profile)
This is the code that I have:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


instagram_url = "https://www.instagram.com"
username = "jlo"

profile = instagram_url + "/" + username

response = requests.get(profile)
print(response.text)

if response.ok:
    html = response.text
    bs_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
    name = bs_html('#react-root > section > main > div > header > section > div.-vDIg > h1')
    print(name) #this should be Jennifer Lopez
```

Code works until `print(response.text)` and it has error in `if statement`

This is the warning that I get:

`UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml").`

And I do not get the name.

Do you know what's the problem? I have also tried this. To download page, and in that way I have used `.find` option and it works amazing (it works for every profile), but when I try to do this with link, it does not work.

Is there a way to do this without using `Selenium`?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#this works

with open('Jennifer.html', encoding = 'utf-8') as html:
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

name = bs.find('h1', class_='rhpdm')
name = str(name).split(">")[1].split("<")[0]
print(name)


#this does not work

html = urlopen('https://www.instagram.com/jlo/')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

name = bs.find('h1', class_='rhpdm')
print(name)
```

Comment: that block gets rendered dynalically

Comment: You need to use selenium to load the information and then use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: can you show me how?

Comment: @KunduK Can you check the updated question, I have added other version of code

Comment: @taga: I don't think so .The page is rendered dynamically by java scripts.Beautifulsoup can't help you in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Scripts using `selenium` `Chrome driver`.
You can download compatible chrome driver from this [link](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) Check your chrome web browser version and download the compatible chrome driver version from above link.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

instagram_url = "https://www.instagram.com"
username = "jlo"
profile = instagram_url + "/" + username
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver=webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(profile)
html=driver.page_source
driver.close()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('.rhpdm').text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! You can do it like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


binary = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' #this should be same if using windows
options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=True)
options.binary = binary
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True #optional
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap, executable_path=r'Your Path') #put your geckodriver path here

#Above code should be the same for most of the time when you scrape.
#Below is the place where you will be making changes

instagram_url = "https://www.instagram.com"
username = "jlo"
profile = instagram_url + "/" + username

driver.get(profile)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
for x in soup.findAll('h1',{'class':'rhpdm'}):
    print(x.text.strip())
driver.quit()
```

Instructions for downloading geckodriver is [here](https://www.guru99.com/gecko-marionette-driver-selenium.html)

Comment: Can you check the updated question, I have added other version of code, with `.find` option

Comment: @taga I don't think it is possible to scrape a web page which is rendered dynamically with JS . without Selenium. Are you having problems with selenium!